# I want to get style attribute's height and width only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want get height from below div using Jquery,

```
<div class="profile-tracker" style="width: 577px; height: 404px; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px; z-index: 290;"></div>
```

Comment: Your title and description are different ?

Comment: You want the height of element or the height mentioned in the style attribute?

Comment: @gurvinder372 What is the difference ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ height of element is a numeric value in pixel and is influenced by other things (like css, etc), while value specified in style attribute could be in percentage as well.

Comment: seeing lot of down-vote for the answers.  any explanation from the down voter??

Comment: @Neetin619, are you down voting the answers? If yes, always provide explanations for the down vote.

Comment: if you do not know the answer please don't down vote

Comment: Your accepted answer is dramatically more complex than needed and not best practice; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166849/157247) is how to do it if you really want to access the inline style `height` value (as opposed to the current height of the element, which may well be different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the `height` value specified in the `style` attribute, then use `reduce` and `split`

```
var styleMap = style.split( ";" ).reduce( ( a, c ) => ( d = c.split( ":" ), a[d[0].trim()] =  String(d[1]).trim(), a ), {}); //get style map
```

**Demo**

```js
//console.log( $( ".profile-tracker" ).attr( "style" ) );

var style = $( ".profile-tracker" ).attr( "style" ); //get style attribute value

var styleMap = style.split( ";" ).reduce( ( a, c ) => ( d = c.split( ":" ), a[d[0].trim()] =  String(d[1]).trim(), a ), {}); //get style map 

console.log( styleMap[ "height" ] ); //get height value specified
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-tracker" style="width: 577px; height: 404px; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px; z-index: 290;"></div>
```

If the style also has `url` in it, then

```js
//console.log( $( ".profile-tracker" ).attr( "style" ) );

var style = $( ".profile-tracker" ).attr( "style" ); //get style attribute value

var styleMap = style.split( ";" ).reduce( ( a, c ) => ( d = c.split( ":" ), a[d[0].trim()] =  String(d[1]).trim(), a ), {}); //get style map 

console.log( styleMap[ "height" ] ); //get height value specified
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-tracker" style="no-repeat url(';../../media/examples/lizard.png') ;width: 577px; height: 404px; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px; z-index: 290;"></div>
```

As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax), syntax of style property is as following

> declaration-list
>
> : S* declaration? [ ';' S* declaration? ]*
>
> ;

**Note**

- For the properties whose values which have ; in it will not give correct output via this approach.

Comment: doubt:  `$('.profile-tracker').css("height")` will do the same right?

Comment: `$('.profile-tracker').css("height")` will give you height of the element which can be influenced by other things (like css, etc), while this answer intends to give the value specified in the style attribute.

Comment: check this fiddle. I have applied the height through css. but still getting the same which is mentioned in the style. https://jsfiddle.net/tpzyzfnb/6/. do you have any example like that?

Comment: oh yes.. now i got it. If some one override the height attribute using `!important` keyword that time it is not giving the actual mentioned height. In that case, this solution given the original height value. But OP never mentioned this problem anywhere on his question. https://jsfiddle.net/tpzyzfnb/10/

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you do all this error-prone work (consider: URLs with `;` in them) rather than just [accessing the `style` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166849/157247)?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I chose this approach since I thought that OP may modify the style value and want to look at the original value given in the markup. I have given an example with url as well. Can you please share an example of css property value with `;` as part of the value? Thanks.

Comment: @gurvinder372: Again, anything with a [`url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) could have a `;` in it. And the `style` property largely does provide access to the original value in the markup: https://jsfiddle.net/5dmqcb27/ Computed styles tend to lose their original units (you get pixels instead), but the `style` property is minimally processed (well, colors that don't use a color name tend to get normalized).

Comment: What I meant was, if the style has been modified before fetching its value https://jsfiddle.net/5dmqcb27/2/, it won't retain the old value.

Comment: Neither will the `style` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/5dmqcb27/3/ Writing to the `style` property modifies the attribute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ohh, in that case you are right about directly using the style attribute only. Negi-Rox has already answered the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this.

```
var z=$(".profile-tracker")
console.log(z[0].style.height);
console.log(z[0].style.width);
```

[image]